# sqoop incremental import reboots VM

Tags: sqoop

I am using the following sqoop command to import MySQL data into hive.

MySQL table:

```
create table student(id int,name varchar(20),rank int,state varchar(20),primary key(id));
 id  | name | rank | state     |
+-----+------+------+-----------+
| 100 | AAA  |    5 | AP        |
| 101 | BBB  |    2 | AP        |
| 102 | CCC  |    1 | Karnataka |
| 103 | DDD  |   10 | Karnataka |
| 104 | EEE  |    2 | AP        |
| 105 | FFF  |    3 | AP        |
| 106 | GGGG |    4 | AP        |
| 107 | HHH  |    5 | AP        |
| 108 | IIII |   15 | Karnataka |
| 109 | JJJJ |    8 | Karnataka 


sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username root --password hadoop --table student --hive-import --fields-terminated-by "," --lines-terminated-by "\n" --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse/test.db
```

sqoop imports data into `test.db/student` directory successfully. I created a hive student table for that location.

I append some rows in MySQL student table, as

```
id  | name | rank | state     |
+-----+------+------+-----------+
| 100 | AAA  |    5 | AP        |
| 101 | BBB  |    2 | AP        |
| 102 | CCC  |    1 | Karnataka |
| 103 | DDD  |   10 | Karnataka |
| 104 | EEE  |    2 | AP        |
| 105 | FFF  |    3 | AP        |
| 106 | GGGG |    4 | AP        |
| 107 | HHH  |    5 | AP        |
| 108 | IIII |   15 | Karnataka |
| 109 | JJJJ |    8 | Karnataka |
| 110 | KKK  |    6 | Karnataka |
| 111 | LLLL |    7 | AP        |
| 112 | MMM  |    9 | AP
```

For importing new inserted rows, I used the sqoop command as

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username root --password hadoop --table student  --fields-terminated-by "," --lines-terminated-by "\n" --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse/test.db --incremental append --check-column id --last-value 109
```

**but this sqoop command is rebooting my VM.** What is the problem? I am not able to find the cause.

I created a job for the same command as,

```
sqoop job --create import-student1 -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username root --password hadoop --table student --incremental append --check-column id --last-value 109 --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse/test.db --fields-terminated-by "," --lines-terminated-by "\n" --direct

sqoop job --exec import-student1
```

**then it shows completed successfully,but data is not importing**

Comment: @JaimeCr I approved your edit. When editing, please also remove things like "Thanks in advance".

Comment: @S.L.Barth Ok, I'll take it into account for future edits.